# Audio buffer size is incorrect on a mac

Tags: objective-c

After a while,developing with the audio unit, i know there is some bug that is well known to devs who works with audio buffers in low level .

The bug is that the buffer size on a mac is wrong and show 512, instead of 1024 , where the same software on a iDevice , shows 1024 .

Question is , there is a way to solve that so i can get on a mac also 1024 bits buffer? its a little bit hard to work like that, because simulation is different from device.

This is the callback function where i check the buffer from the mic input :

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData)
{

    AudioBuffer buffer;
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2;  
    buffer.mData = NULL; 

    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;
    OSStatus status;
    status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit,
                             ioActionFlags,
                             inTimeStamp,
                             inBusNumber,
                             inNumberFrames,
                             &bufferList);


     int16_t *q = (int16_t *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData;


//  inNumberFrames, is 512 on a mac ,and 1024 on a device
```

(speaker output callback is the same by the way=512 bits).

A part of the setting of the audio unit :

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;//44100.00;
audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;
```

Well i found here that someone say you have to set on the mac (retina is mine) the sample rate in the midi tool , i check it out but its 44100 in there . the chanels are 24 bit, i was trying with 16 bits but no good result . still 512 bits buffer size on my mac.
I have a mac retina display 2012.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to consider:
 1) audio units are made to have the buffer sizes set by the host
 2) you can set a max buffer side via overriding AUBase::SetMaxFramesPerSlice(nFrames)
 3) There isn't a function to set a min buffer size.

With that being said, you can customize your code as you see fit by overriding more and more functions in the AUBase class. As far as I know there isn't a way to set a minimum buffer size.  What you can do is store frames into a buffer until you've reached the number you want, and then send out frames.  Just like a circular buffer on a delay effect.

Is there a reason you're wanting a certain number of frames?

Comment: I am doing a heavily DSP on the buffer, so for example if i do FFT transform on the signal , the resolution is different from 512 to 1024 samples . and regarding your answer, there is a way to limit the buffer size in time . but still its a patch , because same code should run on device and mac , and since everyting happens in real time , i can't manipulate the code to do nasty things. there is no  reason the buffer size should be different for a mac and iDevice .  there got to be a way to change that .

Comment: See I would do something like checking for the inFramesToProcess, if it's less than 1024, then store it into an ivar buffer.  When the ivar buffer is full of 1024 samples, do the FFT. 

Here's a simple example of such a buffer: http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=144034

Comment: Actually i have tried that ,i accumulate the buffer, i save it, but somehow the fft gets many zeros..cant figure it out. i think the mac is working with other samples resolution and other amplitudes

Comment: Well a quick way to debug that is print inFramesToProcess to check the frame count.  Can you show me your DSP process()?